# How to use --relaxed-security programatically in Appium?

Tags: javascript, appium, appium-android, browserstack

### The problem

I am using Browser Stack and there I am unable to execute shell commands.

### Environment

- Appium version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue: 1.21.0 is what I am using, but version doesn’t matters.
- Mobile platform/version under test: Android, All Versions
- Real device or emulator/simulator: Browser Stack Devices

### Details

In local we go to advance settings and then update it there but, it is not possible with Browser Stack. Is these a way I can set "relaxed security programatically in javascript?"
If yes, please do share the snippet or examples. If not please suggest how can I run ADB Execute commands on BrowserStack

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

BrowserStack does not support ADB commands but they support how can you achieve the functionality using an alternative approach https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/references/adb-commands-android